# ssl with certbot and nginx on ubuntu

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm trying to add ssl to my website hosted on my VPS (Ubuntu 20). I do not have any skill nginx (v 1.18.0) and I just followed tutorials to add ssl to my website by helping letsEncrypt and certbot.

Here I have some problems:

1. I followed [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx) tutorial and in it's 3rd part I only used `sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com` because I faced error in `sudo certbot --nginx -d www.example.com`. So I decided to just add example.com and forward every request from **[www.appsazz.ir](http://www.appsazz.ir)** to **appsazz.ir** in nginx. Now certbot generated a file inside **/etc/nginx/conf.d** with the name **www.appsazz.ir.conf**.It's configuration did't resolved my problem I tryed to changed it a little. Here is the file configurations:

```
server {
        if ($host = appsazz.ir){
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        if ($scheme != "https"){
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/venus;
    server_name  appsazz.ir www.appsazz.ir;

    # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/appsazz.ir/fullchain.pem; #managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/appsazz.ir/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

`nginx -t` response seems to be ok:

> nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok

> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

why when I request from browser to appsazz.ir it still loads with **not secure?**

2. when I request on [www.appsazz.ir](http://www.appsazz.ir) Chrome responds with **ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED** error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is correct and `appsazz.ir` is loading with `https://` on the browser. I can also see the ssl certificate issued using `let's encrypt`. However `www.appsazz.ir` isn't configured properly in your DNS provider. A quick `nslookup www.appsazz.ir` is showing this:

```
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

** server can't find www.appsazz.ir: NXDOMAIN
```

Please configure the subdomain `www` to point to a valid IP or endpoint and it should work. In your case. `appsazz.ir` points to IP `188.121.122.161`, I guess `www.appsazz.ir` should be pointing to the same.